# Install IOTEdge on Linux

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am following this tutorial:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux

When I try to do sudo apt-get install iotedge

I have the following error

```
xx@xx:/etc/apt $  sudo apt-get install iotedge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 iotedge : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
           Depends: libiothsm-std (= 1.0.9.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work

Comment: You can try installing libssl, you can follow the section "Missing SSL dependencies" from this article: https://www.ft-tudes.com/blog-posts/azure-iot-edge-runtime-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 0):

In your case it seems that the dependencies are causing the problem as per the error.
It can be solved as follow:

For Ubuntu 20.04:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/libi/libiothsm-std/libiothsm-std_1.1.9-1_arm64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libiothsm-std_1.1.9-1_arm64.deb
rm libiothsm-std_1.1.9-1_arm64.deb libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb
```

For Ubuntu 18.04:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.13_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i "libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.13_amd64.deb"
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod/pool/main/libi/libiothsm-std/libiothsm-std_1.0.8-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libiothsm-std/libiothsm-std_1.0.8-2_amd64.deb
rm libiothsm-std/libiothsm-std_1.0.8-2_amd64.deb libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.13_amd64.deb
```

this shall do the job. I have basically just downloaded the dependencies from the Ubuntu repositories using `wget` and installed them  using `dpkg` in 2nd step 2 times for each repository. Then I have removed the repositories using rm after they have been installed because you won't need the files anymore.

Hope your problem is solved now!!